# App compatibility issues in Xcode15 bitrise build

Tags: ios, cocoapods, exit-code, xcode15, bitrise

Currently, I am using Xcode 13.x, now I am upgrading it to Xcode 15. Local it is working fine but when I build it using Bitrise it is throwing me the error
"*Building for 'iOS-simulator', but linking in dylib (/Users/XXXXXXXX/git/Pods/CLuceneWrapper/CLuceneWrapper.framework/CLuceneWrapper) built for 'iOS'
Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)*"

I have tried setting "Excluded Architectures to arm64" as suggested in some of the portals. But it is still not working.
Can anyone help me in this regard?